# Is there a way to match draggable and droppable id's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am buldiing drag and drop puzzle game. I have draggables(images) on the left and droppable(divs) on the right. As you can see they all have unique id like 
"img_1" and  "drop_1" , so basically i want to match them by their id's number in this case that is "_number". If i succeed this ,i think i can develop some logic i need.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="tasks">
      <img class="task" id="img_1" src="img/puzz1.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_2" src="img/puzz2.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_3" src="img/puzz3.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_4" src="img/puzz4.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_5" src="img/puzz5.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_6" src="img/puzz6.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_7" src="img/puzz7.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_8" src="img/puzz8.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_9" src="img/puzz9.jpg" >



     

    </div>

    <div id="drops">
      <div id="drop_1" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_2" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_3" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_4" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_5" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_6" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_7" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_8" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_9" class="box2"></div>



    </div>
```

Logic should be looking like this:

```
if(draggable id "_number" != dropabble id"_number"){return to original position}

else{stay in that droppable}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Simple just added "data-id='a' on draggable elements" , and also added "data-id='a' on droppable elements as well(must be the same data id)".

Next thing to do is just to match them in jQuery with attr and that would be it.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".task").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
  $(".box2").droppable({ 
      accept: function(drag) {
          var dropId = $(this).attr('data-id');
          var dragId = $(drag).attr('data-id');
          return dropId === dragId;
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="tasks">
      <img class="task" data-id='a' id="img_1" src="img/puzz1.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_2" src="img/puzz2.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_3" src="img/puzz3.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_4" src="img/puzz4.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_5" src="img/puzz5.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_6" src="img/puzz6.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_7" src="img/puzz7.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_8" src="img/puzz8.jpg" >
      <img class="task" id="img_9" src="img/puzz9.jpg" >



     

    </div>

    <div id="drops">
      <div id="drop_1" data-id='a' class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_2" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_3" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_4" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_5" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_6" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_7" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_8" class="box2"></div>
      <div id="drop_9" class="box2"></div>



    </div>
  </div>
```

I also didn't do for all my elements, but i will do that. I just wanted to post the answer.